# Tectonic under text editors

Tags: texmaker, editors, tectonic

[Tectonic](https://tectonic-typesetting.github.io/en-US/) seems to be a great project.

> I am wondering if I can call Tectonic from a text editor (ideally Texmaker or Texstudio)?

If I understand well, Tectonic is a command-line which is quite (not interactive) so not practical when it goes to correct latex errors!

Comment: surely you can run any command from your editor, why would you not be able to call tectonic?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know how to call an external program from Texmaker (for example). I tried to replace xelatex with tectonic in Commands configuration of  texmaker...without success!

Comment: Can you say exactly what you did to change the configuration and/or show us the "Commands" and "Quick Build" pages of TeXmaker's config? Can you be more specific about "without success" means: what happened when you tried? I would think that texmaker or texstudio would process the .log file for error reporting and correction, not the console output of the command, so its being "quiet" shouldn't matter.

Comment: @user56980 Why are the advantages of Tectonic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually quite easy to use tectonic with texmaker. After installing tectonic and texmaker, e.g. on Mac

```
brew install tectonic
brew install --cask texmaker
```

you can start texmaker. Then navigate to `Preferences->Quick Build` and select `User`. In the text field enter the following command

```
tectonic %.tex --keep-logs
```

[image: texmaker preferences]

That's it. Now you can compile your document simply starting `Quick Build` and then `View PDF`.

See also https://tectonic-typesetting.github.io/book/latest/ref/v1cli.html .